# magento: get variable from block or hlper into javascript file

Tags: magento

I am including a js file via the layout xml:

for example:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>myjs.js</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

This is fine. But, i am setting up an ajax call inside myjs.js and would like to pull the post url from a helper class.

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your reference to the `head` I would add a block which would output a partial that sets a js var ahead of the myjs.js file being added.

For instance:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="page/html" name="mycustomblock" template="page/html/mycustomblock.phtml"/>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>myjs.js</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

And your file mycustomblock.phtml would contain:

```
<?php

// below is javascript that is being populated by your helper
?>
<script> var myblogpost = <?php echo Mage::helper('mycustom/helper')->blogPostUrl();?>; </script>
```

Comment: yea. I recommend this way. If you want to have PHP-Variables in JS-files you have to parse the files, then you can't cache them easy and the client to, you have problems with content-servers, CDN,...